# Write to a file from a list with integer Python

Tags: python, list, file

Im trying to write a text file from a list, it works perfectly with a list of strings, each element gets on a new line. But when I try to write from a list with integers it does not work. 
The thing is I need that list as an integer-list in another place in the code (when comparing values in an if-statement), and I've tried to convert the integer-list to a string-list, but then the numbers gets placed on separate lines like for e.g.,

I have to write 2016 in one line:

```
2016
```

but, it gets like this

```
2
0
1
6
```

here is the code for writing to a text file:

print("write year: ")
year.append(int(input()))

...some code that needs the list year as an integer...

year_string = str(year)

```
with open('movietitle.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(movietitle))

with open('year_string.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(year_string))

with open('genre.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(genre))

with open('review.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(review))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

years = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

with open('year.txt', 'w') as file:
    for year in years:
        file.write("%i\n" % year)
```

gives

```
$ cat year.txt 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes... if there is more than one number (e.g 10) it should be stored in one line like that.. I'll try

Comment: Note that using %i\n solution provided here works better than str() solution provided by @Neil above, as it saves long integers as is without adding exponentials.

Answer (score 8):

Since you used the variable name `year` I think you're trying to convert a string integer of year, so here's how you'd do that.  I am also suspect this is the issue because of the odd output you're getting. I also added code on how to one-line convert years to a string version of itself.

### Writing an integer to a file

```
year = 1998
with open('year.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join([str(year)]))
```

### Writing a list of integers to a file

```
years = [1998,1996]
with open('year2.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(str(year) for year in years))
```

### (Per request of the original poster):

```
years = [1998,1996]
with open('year2.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(years))
```

Comment: "Writing a list of integers to a file"

Comment: The thing is, first the list is an integer (year.append(int(input())) because I need it as an integer somewhere else in the code. And then i convert it to a String...

Comment: should it be: file.write('\n'.join(str(year2) for year in years)) ? u forgot "year2"

Comment: Try using the string version of it, just updated it.  And if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: Almost right, it creates an array in an array.. so when I'm trying to read from the file and store it in a list, both (e.g 1998, 2016) gets stored in the first element in the new list.

Comment: It stores the values in the text file like this: [1998, 2016] , instead of:

Comment: Try the new suggestion just added

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work.. it worked with the solution at the buttom by rinn2883

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the integers to strings.

```
with open('year_string.txt', 'w') as file:
file.write('\n'.join(year_string))
```

Needs to be:

```
with open('year_string.txt', 'w') as file:
file.write(str('\n'.join(year_string)))
```

Comment: sorry mate doesn't work. Seems like the '\n' that is putting each number in a new line

Answer (score 0):

As I know, by definition the parameter of write method has to be text (string) or byte. Cannot be int or float.

method definition: file.write(byte)

This worked for me:

```
years = [1998.45, 1996, 2002.55, 2010.2487]

with open('years.txt', 'w') as file:
    for year in years:
        file.write(str(year))
        file.write('\n')
```

Finally if I needed these numbers in arithmetic format (integer or float)

I would change them to int or floats, when I loaded them from the txt file.

[result writing in the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg0nx.png)