# How to read and write integers from text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

float values into a file.
When I try with .write() it takes the input as a string.
I guess it's really basic of Python but I'm new to it.
Hope you guys will not get angry with this question :D

```
with open('C:/Python35/sample.txt', 'w') as f:
    data = [70, 60, 55, 75, 95, 90, 80, 80, 85, 100]
    for i in data:
        f.write('%d \n' % i)

with open('C:/Python35/sample.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as g:
    data = g.readlines()

print(data)
```

if I run this, I can get the result like below.

```
['70 \n', '60 \n', '55 \n', '75 \n', '95 \n', '90 \n', '80 \n', '80 \n', '85 \n', '100 \n']
```

It's the list of string, not the int values. 
(And also wonder why there is '\n' in the 'data' list!)

Comment: @DYZ I understand the confusion given the common titles but this question is asking about reading/writing integer values while [Write to a file from a list with integer Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208296/write-to-a-file-from-a-list-with-integer-python) only addresses the writing part. I do not believe this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have your `sample.txt` file formatted something like this:

```
70
60
55
75
95
90
80
80
85
100
```

There's nothing in that file that remembers the value you inserted is an integer and since it is a text document (`.txt`) it isn't going to encode the numbers as such either. As for the `\n`, each number is on its own line meaning there has to be some character signifying a newline, hence the `\n` newline character.

If you look at this line in your code:

```
f.write('%d \n' %i)
```

you are explicitly writing the `\n` after each number. If you want to read the numbers from the text file and have them be integers, you must explicitly convert the string value to its integer representation. You could rewrite that logic to:

```
>>> with open("sample.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as g:
...     data = list(map(int, g.readlines()))
... 
>>> data
[70, 60, 55, 75, 95, 90, 80, 80, 85, 100]
```

where it will map the `int` type onto each value of the list returned by `g.readlines()` and then convert the `map` object to a `list` again. And, if you were wondering, `int` disregards whitespace (spaces and newlines) like you have in each line.

```
>>> int("70 \n")
70
>>> type(int("60 \n"))
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` you see on the console is merely Python's default `repr`esentation of a string. If you want to write lines of data to a file and print a file line by line, you could do this (all I did was iterate over your list and print it one line at a time instead of printing the array):

```
with open('C:/Python35/sample.txt', 'w') as f:
    data = [70, 60, 55, 75, 95, 90, 80, 80, 85, 100]
    for i in data:
        f.write('%d \n' %i)

with open('C:/Python35/sample.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as g:
    data=g.readlines()

for line in data:
    print(line)
```

Comment: the `\n` is _not_ apart of the default representation of a string, it is simply a newline in the text document.

Comment: I mean to say that calling `repr(some_string)`, where that strong has new lines, will print out `\n`, which is precisely what happens when you try to print out a list of strings.

Comment: I believe that newline is caused by the `end` keyword argument in the `print` function, which is defaulted to `\n`. Try calling `print(repr(6), end="")` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print))

Answer (score 0):

The method **readlines()** reads until EOF using readline() and returns a list containing the lines.

Open sample.txt with notepad o from prompt execute: `type sample.txt`