# Converting load cell data to .txt file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, export-to-text

I am trying to gather data from my load cell that is hooked up to a raspberry pi 3B. I have the script reading data but am trying to figure out how to export that data into a .txt file.

I have seen some info on how to create .txt files with text but not much for integers. I need something more fit to my application.

The script takes x (not sure on the exact value) samples of data per second so the amount of data can vary depending on how long I run the script. I want a text file to be created once I stop the script and record the data points on separate lines like in the attached image. I found a way to do it with words/letters but integers wouldn't work.

Let me know if there is anything I can share to help find a solution easier. I appreciate all the input.

Comment: ??? Are you looking for something more complicated than `print(f"{timestamp},{value}")`?

Comment: I am looking to stop the script and have the data collected be converted to a list on a txt file. Im not looking for one value to be printed

Comment: Does [Write to a file from a list with integer Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208296/write-to-a-file-from-a-list-with-integer-python) answer your question?

Comment: `not looking for one value to be printed ` - couldn't you write a single value each time you receive one?

Comment: Why don't you show us a concrete example of what you're expecting in your data file?

Comment: I added an answer below with a more concrete example @timroberts

Comment: There is no difference between printing words to a file and printing integers to a file.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use "open" with the "w" mode to create a new file:

```
file = open("load_cell_data.txt", "w")
```

Pass the data in with `file.write` and then close the file with `file.close`.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: This does not address his question in any way.